# WordPress: how best can I categorize Woocommerce products by registered system users?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for a reasonable way to allow specific site users to manage their own little online stores such that each user of a specific role of users/registered site members can associate themselves with their own products.

Is there a 'right way' to set up a relation between these two separate content types? I would like to then offer a global search of all products that could be filtered by the creator and the product previews and details would include a link back to the creator's details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ACF and assign the Product post type to a User.

*EDIT*

The *User* Relationship ACF fields is only available in ACF Pro, it appears. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/

Without using ACF, you are essentially creating a new piece of postmeta for the Product post type called `user_id`.  This is good for a one-to-many relationship between Users and Products.

If Products can have more than one User, I would create an intermediary table called `wp_users_products`, or something similar, to establish the many-to-many relationship.